# WCF Rest/Entity Framework - View Not Deserializing as expected

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-rest

I have a view that returns data like the following:

1 | Abita | NULL | http://www.abita.com/
2 | Abita | Abbey Ale | http://abita.com/brews/abbey_ale.php

I am using WCF REST to get the xml representation of this view, via an entity framework object.  When viewing the returned data as xml in a browser, the first row shows data as I expect:

```
    <vw_Url z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
- <EntityKey z:Id="i2" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
  <a:EntityContainerName>FierceBeersEntities</a:EntityContainerName> 
- <a:EntityKeyValues>
- <a:EntityKeyMember>
  <a:Key>Brewery</a:Key> 
  <a:Value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Abita</a:Value> 
  </a:EntityKeyMember>
  </a:EntityKeyValues>
  <a:EntitySetName>vw_Url</a:EntitySetName> 
  </EntityKey>
  <Beer i:nil="true" /> 
  <Brewery>Abita</Brewery> 
  <RowId>1</RowId> 
  <Url>http://www.abita.com/</Url> 
  </vw_Url>
```

However, the second row doesn't appear to deserialize the row/object correctly, as it doesn't contain the data from row two.

```
<vw_Url z:Ref="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
```

Any idea why this might be?

UPDATE: 
I've tracked this down to being caused by a UNION within the view.  The rows are unioned together from two different tables, and for some reason, EF is treating the second as a reference to the first.  Perhaps this is an EF bug?  Any ideas for a workaround?

Sounds like this may be an EF bug/limitation in EF 1.0.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9293cf4d-deef-40b1-ab56-a0ee1e770dd9  However, I am using EF 4.0 and it still seems to be an issue.  Sigh...

Comment: Can you verify that the Entity Framework loads both rows? Is there any restriction/limitation to return only a single row?

Comment: Entity Framework is not loading both rows correctly.  It is loading both rows, however, the second is a duplicate of the first.  There is no restriction limiting only a single row returned.  When using SQL Profiler, the query executed returns the expected data, but EF appears to be loading it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I've tracked this down to being caused by a UNION within the view. The rows are unioned together from two different tables, and for some reason, EF is treating the second as a reference to the first. Perhaps this is an EF bug?

Sounds like this may be an EF bug/limitation in EF 1.0. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9293cf4d-deef-40b1-ab56-a0ee1e770dd9 However, I am using EF 4.0 and it still seems to be an issue. Sigh...